# Why am I able to call my action creators without a mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

Can someone help explain why the below code is able to access the **mySubmitAction** action creator **without** including mapDispatchToProps()? I understand handleSubmit() is provided as a prop by the reduxForm() decorator, but where is my custom action creator being passed in?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as Actions from '../actions';

const validate = values => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!values.title) {
        errors.title = "Please enter a title"
    }

    return errors;
};

class myForm extends Component {
    handleFormSubmit = (values) => {
        this.props.mySubmitAction(values);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            isOpen={ this.props.modalIsOpen }
            onRequestClose={ () => this.props.onRequestClose() }>

            <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit)}>
                <input name="title" className="form-control" type="text"  />
                <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

const createReduxForm = reduxForm({form: 'myForm', validate});
export default connect(null, Actions)(createReduxForm(SessionForm));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `import * as Actions from '../actions`, `Actions` is an object mapping of your action name and action creators. When you pass an object as `mapDispatchToProps` parameter, `connect` will by default wrap each action creator into a `dispatch` call.

See [react-redux connect API](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

> [mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function): If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.

Comment: ok I think I understand. But then why would I use mapDispatchToProps when I can just pass in my Actions object to connect() directly?

Comment: Sometimes you just want to expose a subset of the action creators to the components, you may want to inject default arguments to the action creators, or conditionally select action creators. The idea is that you can encapsulate the actions in mapDispatchToProps instead of putting the logic in the components.